# Custom attribute in response from SAML

Tags: active-directory, saml-2.0, adfs, ws-federation

I use SAML ( Ws-Fed ) to authenticate the user via an IdP.
I make my AuthnRequest and I correctly receive a response.

In this response I got 4 attributes ( Id, FirstName, LastName, Email ).

I need to also receive the AD groups and the roles.

I don't know if it's someting I can add in my AuthnRequest ( ask for more attributes ) or if it's something that need to be handle by the IdP ?

I don't know much about SAML and ADFS, i have done some research but what I tried didnt work for now

Answer (score 0):

The idP needs to have those values configured. Another thing is if it can actually provide them.